# Running M-x sql-postgres in emacs on windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, emacs

When I try to run an inferior `psql` process in emacs on windows, I seem to be getting no response.  This seems to be a [known problem](http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-general@postgresql.org/msg84401.html) the solution of which is to install the cygwin version of `psql`.  Unfortunately, the cygwin `psql` appears to do absolutely nothing, even `psql -V` does nothing.  Does anyone have a solution to either of these problems or an easy way of sending queries from emacs to postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out how to get the cygwin psql to run.  It seems that the provided cygpq.dll was missing some entry point,

```
strace -o /dev/null psql --version
```

Responded with "The procedure entrypoint PQencryptPassword
could not be located in the dynamic link library cygpq.dll."

I replaced the cygwin provided cygpq.dll with a locally compiled one and it appears that we are now cooking with gas.  I need to learn more about cygwin dynamic linking.  I thank all of you for your patient support.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not going to be a good answer, but I am not currently on a Windows machine with Emacs or PostGres, so I can't work out a better solution for you.

That said, are you able to run psql in a command shell? If so, perhaps you can try starting the shell (`M-x shell`) or the [Eshell](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryEshell) (`M-x eshell`) to start an inferior shell and running `psql` from there.

I was originally going to suggest that you call `M-x shell-command` (also `M-!`) and then specify `psql &` for your command. The `&` lets Emacs know that you want to run the shell command asynchronously. However, [this entry](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecuteExternalCommand#toc4) on the EmacsWiki indicates that it will not work on Windows. You might try it anyway and see what happens...

Comment: Unfortunately I see the same behavior for either the cygwin psql or the windows one in the emacs command shell regardless of whether I run cygwin bash or the windows command shell.

The same thing happens with M-! with either the cygwin or windows psql (the & works, I think because I have emacs using the cygwin bash by default.)

I guess that I am stuck using my linux laptop to do work.

Thanks for the attempt

Comment: But does it work if you just attempt to run psql from a windows command shell that isn't inside of emacs?

Comment: Yes, the windows one does, the cygwin does not.  The problem with the windows one has something to do with missing readline and behaving strangely in what it thinks are noninteractive shells.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem (but could not make the cygwin psql work).

Eventually, I discovered that both M-x sql-postgres and psql call in M-x shell are in fact interactive but without a visible prompt; i.e., one can type commands (at the very beginning of the last line) and they get executed as expected.

Before I realized that I had modified my postgres password file in order to avoid the password prompt and the initial hang of the psql call in M-x shell:

When the defaults aren't quite right, you can save yourself some typing by setting the environment variables PGDATABASE, PGHOST, PGPORT and/or PGUSER to appropriate values. (For additional environment variables, see the documentation.) It is also convenient to have a ~/.pgpass file to avoid regularly having to type in passwords. See the documentation for more information. (http://linux.die.net/man/1/psql)